# Select random record from table with further conditions in C# code

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I'm coding little process where I can select random record from table, where field with checkbox/boolean is also unchecked.
The moral of the story is to select random record, work with it and set checkbox/boolean field == Checked.

I have approach this work by selecting random record from Count() method, I got Integer in return and I can choose random number from that pool. But I also need to filter the query to select only records who have the checkbox/boolean field unchecked, but I haven't managed in the following code to go so far.

I have used Lambda expression as follows but maybe better way can exists.

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DatabaseModelContainer mc = new DatabaseModelContainer();
        MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next(myTable.Count);

        string selectedRec = myTable.MyField.OrderBy(r => myTable.MyField).Take(index).ToString();

        //Selected record to be shown at the screen, but will not appear (only reference point is shown) 
        Console.WriteLine(selectedRec);

        //Selected random value is displayed here and that indeed worked, I get random value there, but I can't use the id to select record above based on that id.
        Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Code above does NOT show who to choose random record WHERE CheckboxField == Checked, so that code needs to be added as well.

What approach is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `MyTable` is a sequence, the correct way of doing it should be :

```
var randomRecord = myTable
    .Where(x => x.CheckboxField)
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Full Example:**

See it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4JLU0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    class TableRow 
    {
        public int I {get;set;}
        public bool CheckboxField {get;set;}

        TableRow(int i)
        {
            this.I = i;
            this.CheckboxField = (i % 3 == 0); //in our demo, assume that some are already checked, some aren't
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TableRow> GenerateTableRows(int howMany)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<howMany; i++)
            {
                yield return new TableRow(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    Program() 
    {
        ICollection<TableRow> myTable = new List<TableRow>(TableRow.GenerateTableRows(12));
        while (myTable.Count(x => !x.CheckboxField) > 0) //keep looping until we've processed all records
        {
            var randomRecord = GetRandomRecord(myTable);
            Console.WriteLine(randomRecord == null ? "No Matching Rows Exist" : randomRecord.I.ToString()); 
        }
    }

    TableRow GetRandomRecord(ICollection<TableRow> myTable)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(); //we could optionally provide this as a parameter too to avoid recreating each time
        var randomRecord = myTable
            .Where(x => !x.CheckboxField)
            .ToList()
            .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
            .FirstOrDefault();  
        if(randomRecord != null) //avoid issue if all items are checked
        {
            randomRecord.CheckboxField = true; //mark this record as having been processed
        }
        return randomRecord;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But does that determine that random record should be Checkboxfield == Unchecked?

Comment: The random record will be only selected from those whose `CheckboxField` is checked. If you would like to select randomly from the unchecked ones, use `.Where(x => !x.CheckboxField)` instead.

Comment: I tried that but I got the following error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @Sandri Add a `.ToList()` between `Where` and `OrderBy`

Comment: Thanks that did help. But there is no random selection, it display always the first record, does it have something to do with index variable ?

Comment: @Sandri Do you have more than one record with `CheckboxField` set, other than the first record?

Comment: I have many records in my DB yes, and now all of them are unchecked. I think the selection has something to do with .FirstOrDefault() method, so let's say some records are checked, then the variable will take all unchecked record and sort them with the lowest counter value - am I right? It's crusial for me to select some random record regardless of count value. Because if FirstOrDefault() is selecting the lowest counter value the selection will always be in order, not randomly - am I right?

Comment: The `order by` is ordering by a random number; therefore `FirstOrDefault` selects the first item from a randomly ordered list; i.e. a random record.  Here's the code in a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4JLU0.

Comment: ps. I noticed in your question you'd asked to find all objects where the checkbox isn't checked; the original answer found those which were checked; just adding an exclamation mark (not) before that value in the `Where` statement will resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do this:

```
var randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
var randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.Next(myTable.Count(r => r.CheckboxField)) - 1;

myTable
    .Where(r => r.CheckboxField)
    .Skip(randomNumber)
    .Select(r => r.DesiredColumn)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi there - This work indeed, but output is the count value. I need to select value of one field in the table. How can I do that based on the random count value?

Comment: Then you'd just add a .Select(r => r.YourField) After the Skip. This also keeps you from populating a lot of the results in memory by returning it all with a ToList(). At most one result is returned by SQL and at least, a null is returned if there is nothing in the table. By doing .Where(x => x.CheckboxField).ToList() you return all results into memory that meet that criteria (maybe it's a lot, maybe it isn't. I don't know). This way you offload that query completely to the database server. As it stands you could potentially be loading a lot of data into memory just to get one result.